# Vertical Align Image with CSS Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have looked at other examples here, but seem to work. I have a small amount of text and an image aligned left inside a blue div. As the page gets narrower the text sizes down properly in the div, but the image remains in the top left of the div. I would like it to stay in the vertical center of the div. It can get larger or stay the same size, I just need it to move to center.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nydbhkkp/1/)

```css
body, h4 {
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#333333;
}
* {
    padding:0px;
}
.warning {
    line-height:1.5em;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#0c203d;
    padding-left:60px;
}
.blueBox {
    background-color:#D4DDF7;
    min-height:50px;
    max-height:150px;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
.icon {
    padding:0;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 735px) and (max-width:1400px) {
    .warning {
        font-size:16px;
        padding-top:14px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width:734px) {
        .warning {
            font-size:13px;
            padding-top:1px;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 200px) and (max-width:320px) {
        .warning {
            font-size:12px;
            padding-top:1px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_countyText">
        <p class="text">To find road conditions use the County selection box or simply click on a County on the searchable map. To view ALL Counties at once, Choose ALL COUNTIES from the dropdown, and click Go.
            <br />Map is not visible on small screens.</p>
        <div class="blueBox">
            <img class="icon" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch/grayscale" alt="Arrow Icon" width="50px" height="50px" />
             <h4 class="warning">THIS VIEW DOES NOT CONTAIN STORM RELATED EMERGENCY ROAD CONDITIONS.</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- End blueBox -->
        <p>To view our progress on STORM Related closings, Visit our <a href="http://dbw.scdot.org/RoadConditions2/default.aspx" class="textLink">Work Plan and Current Closures</a> site.</p>
        <p><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessageCty" class="bText rText">See Results Below</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: put your code in the question

Comment: The image needs to remain left aligned, just moved down to center-left.

Comment: A link to JSFiddle is provided.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

You must specify `display:inline-table` to your `.icon` and `.warning` class. Also as you have image so you must not directly apply `vertically-align:middle;`, better if you wrap it around div/span.

[Working : Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nydbhkkp/2/)

```css
body,
h4 {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333333;
}
* {
  padding: 0px;
}
.warning {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0c203d;
  padding-left: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.blueBox {
  background-color: #D4DDF7;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  display: table;
}
.icon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 735px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .warning {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 734px) {
    .warning {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 320px) {
    .warning {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_countyText">
      <p class="text">To find road conditions use the County selection box or simply click on a County on the searchable map. To view ALL Counties at once, Choose ALL COUNTIES from the dropdown, and click Go.
        <br />Map is not visible on small screens.</p>
      <div class="blueBox"> <span class="icon"><img  src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch/grayscale" alt="Arrow Icon" width="50px" height="50px" /></span>

        <h4 class="warning">THIS VIEW DOES NOT CONTAIN STORM RELATED EMERGENCY ROAD CONDITIONS.</h4>

      </div>
      <!-- End blueBox -->
      <p>To view our progress on STORM Related closings, Visit our <a href="http://dbw.scdot.org/RoadConditions2/default.aspx" class="textLink">Work Plan and Current Closures</a> site.</p>
      <p><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessageCty" class="bText rText">See Results Below</span>

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent. That is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float` from the `.icon` element and `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. Put the below code in whichever breakpoint you'd like to see this behavior.

```
.icon {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your `@media` queries have some issues, so I've edited them in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nydbhkkp/4/).

```css
body,h4 {
 font-family:Gotham,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#333;
}

* {
 padding:0;
}

.warning {
 line-height:1.5em;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#0c203d;
 padding-left:60px;
}

.blueBox {
 background-color:#D4DDF7;
 min-height:50px;
 max-height:150px;
 padding:0;
 text-align:left;
 border-radius:10px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}

.icon {
 padding:0;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .icon {
        float: none !important;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_countyText">
            <p class="text">To find road conditions use the County selection box or simply click on a County on the searchable map. To view ALL Counties at once, Choose ALL COUNTIES from the dropdown, and click Go.
                <br />Map is not visible on small screens.</p>
            <div class="blueBox">
                <img class="icon" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch/grayscale" alt="Arrow Icon" width="50px" height="50px" />
                 <h4 class="warning">THIS VIEW DOES NOT CONTAIN STORM RELATED EMERGENCY ROAD CONDITIONS.</h4>

            </div>
            <!-- End blueBox -->
            <p>To view our progress on STORM Related closings, Visit our <a href="http://dbw.scdot.org/RoadConditions2/default.aspx" class="textLink">Work Plan and Current Closures</a> site.</p>
            <p><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessageCty" class="bText rText">See Results Below</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using media queries at specified breakpoints, you're typically safe to use `display: table` on a parent and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the children in order to vertically align their contents.

In the snippet below, I have removed most of your HTML to better outline the elements to which the CSS actually applies. This should help anyone else who happens to land on this question. Also, I replaced the img tag since an arrow in this case is not semantic content and it made things easier to style.

```css
body { font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

/* ------------------ Start Important Part ------------------ */

.warning {
    display: table; /* Set container as table */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D4DDF7;
}
.warning > * {
    display: table-cell; /* Set children as table-cell */
    padding: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle; /* Vertically center children */
}

/* ------------------- End Important Part ------------------- */

/* Icon */
.warning > .icon { width: 50px; }
.warning > .icon::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch/grayscale");
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

/* Warning text */
.warning > p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0c203d;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="warning">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <p>THIS VIEW DOES NOT CONTAIN STORM RELATED EMERGENCY ROAD CONDITIONS.</p>
</div>
```